# Increment integer in range without conditional operators

Tags: integer, range, conditional-statements, increment, modulo

A simple task - increment an integer in the range 1 to 4, initial value of 1:

`i = (i + 1) < 5 ? i + 1 : 1`

However, I would like to do it without the conditional, so I thought OK, the `%` is the solution, `% 4` will give me 0 to 3, add 1 and it is done:

`i = (i + 1) % 4 + 1`

however, this expression only produces value 3 and 1. With initial value 1 `2 % 4` is 2, add 1 for an end result of 3. And for 3 `4 % 4` is 0, add 1 and we are back to 1.

So is it possible to do it in one expression without conditional operators?

Answer (score 0):

mod operator is actually that simple but powerfull expression

A = A - ((A / MOD) × MOD)

if you modif it like that you can get what you want

A = A + 1 - ((A/MOD) × MOD)

Note that when you dividing A to MOD I assume you will be cast result to integer. For example 1 / 4 = 0.25, after casting integer it is 0.